# How can I read from multiple cache keys in Ruby simultaneously?

Tags: ruby, caching, redis, memcached

I have a bunch of cache keys I want the value of in a Ruby model. How can I retrieve them simultaneously (or in a batch) rather than having to loop through each key and sequentially request the data?

I am currently using memcached but am considering a switch to using Redis for caching.

Edit: I just found this https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/106 - looks like it's built-in. Anyone have anything else to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to rails docs [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemCacheStore.html#method-i-read_multi) ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore has a method read_multi which can do multi-get with memcache